# Elasticsearch Highlighting Issue with fragmentor

Tags: elasticsearch

I am finding issues with how Elasticsearch highlights the text
Example: 
1. when using "unified" highlighter i.e.,

```
 "highlight": {
        "type" : "unified",
        "fields": {
            "*": {}
        }
```

the results shown is :

```
"highlight": {
                    "FILE_CONTENT": [
                        "follows: \n1)Test Clause\n1.1) test 29_May\nDummy values - \is - INR  \is - <em>standard</em>",
                        "<em>whitespace</em> \nStart Date is - 05/31/2018 \nhgdhdrgdffggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggjerklwagggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg"
                    ]
```

we can see Ball and bearing are highlighted together but shown as different elements of highlight array. 
2. The same when using "fvh" highlighter solves the issue :

```
"highlight": {
        "type" : "fvh",

        "fields": {
            "*": {}
        }
    }
```

Highlighting for this is :

```
 "highlight": {
                    "FILE_CONTENT": [
                        "Currency is - INR  \is - <em>standard whitespace</em> \nStart Date is - 05/31/2018 \nhgdhdrgdffgggg"
                    ]
                }
```

For some speed issues, i can not use Fvh highlighter. I am restricted to use unified highlighter
According to [Elasticsearch reference module](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html#specify-fragmenter) "fragmentor":"span" should solve this issue. But i am getting the same issue as when not using "fragmentor" : "span".

```
"highlight": {
        "type" : "unified",
        "fragmenter": "span",
        "fields": {
            "*": {}
        }
    }
```

The results are:

```
"highlight": {
 "FILE_CONTENT": [
                        "follows: \n1)Test Clause\n1.1) test 29_May\nDummy values - \nCurrency is - INR  \is - <em>standard</em>",
                        "<em>whitespace</em> \nStart Date is - 05/31/2018 \nhgdhdrgdffggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggjerklwagggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg"
                    ] 
}
```

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue ?

Comment: is this resolve?